# Preserve output when connecting components (such as speaker) in parallel

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, audio

I'm trying to amplify noise at the node "amplified_noise_output".

When the 8 Ω speaker is ON, the noise is pretty much white and the FFT is flat, as desired. You can see this in the first Picoscope image. However, if I **substitute** the speaker with a 10 Ω resistor (the closest I have to 8 Ω to try to replicate the speaker impedance), the output FFT is not flat at all! It even looks like the op-amp is positively saturating (why?).

I want to be able to have a speaker whose volume is controlled by a potentiometer, but I wish to keep the "amplified_noise_output" voltage intact, regardless of speaker volume. This is because I want to link the "amplified_noise_output" to a comparator that compares if the noise is greater or less than a certain threshold and stores it into a shift register controlled by a microcontroller - again, regardless of speaker volume. But I'm not even able to correctly substitute the speaker with a single 10 Ω resistor, as you can see on the second Picoscope image.

Note: I know that controlling the potentiometer changes the impedance of the circuit, so I'm not sure this would be possible - but would be close enough to have an ON/OFF switch for the speaker if the potentiometer idea is not possible.

My attempt: I tried to use another op-amp (the other pins of the same NE5532P IC) as shown in the "attempt" section of the circuit. I used the "amplified_noise_output" as the positive input and a potentiometer to set the volume. Then I used a non-inverting amplification with a small gain, followed by the speaker. The idea was to have the "amplified_noise_output" seeding another amplification that would be controlled by a potentiometer and a speaker as output. But did not preserve the noise.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbSpzT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't know why you want to use the output of an opamp that delivers only small numbers of mA to drive a speaker or a resistor presenting such a high load. And I certainly don't want to try and explain why the output looks better with a speaker than a resistor here. Have you already qualified your noise generator? I seem to recall you were struggling with that, weeks ago. Is that resolved? If so, what's that circuit look like? (Need to see it to see what loads it can successfully drive.) Finally, are you willing to just buy something like a TDA8551 or LM386 to drive your speaker?

Comment: @periblepsis you are right. I changed the schematic (I didn't want to overcomplicate it but I understand the question needs all the details of what I'm trying to do). So it now has the fully constructed schematic and the idea I want to achieve. I don't mind buying the LM386, but I'm afraid that it would introduce unwanted noise to the output. I'd say the noise generator is working well as for now the speaker output is pretty loud and the amplification gets about to 0.5 Vpp, which is enough to be audible and compared (by the comparator)

Comment: So, your thoughts are to avoid the use of audio amplifiers because they are 'noisy', as you currently believe them to be. Yet, you want noise. But you don't want *any* noise, just the *noise* your generator is making? (This might make sense if you were a scientist who was trying to apply physical theory to the noise generator to predict its behavior and wanted to see how well it matched. But I'm not sure that's your case.) So I gather you want the lowest possible ***added*** noise. Are you aware that this is a *huge* function matching loads to your noise source???

Comment: @periblepsis So do you recommend not using the speaker at all as it would take too much from the op-amps I'm using? If I use the LM386 as you suggested, should I substitute the LF353P in order to provide more power to the circuit? I'm still learning electronics, so I'm sorry if I come across as ignorant in some aspects. It's because I'm learning as I go. Even though I had circuit theory in college, I'm discovering that it is quite different in practice with circuit design, and I never did something with audio/speakers before

Comment: A lot depends on what you want to achieve and if you even know what that is, very well. If this is about creating a high quality random number generator for software, that would be one thing. If this is about some kind of experimentation, then a clear description of the goals would be appropriate, I think. A "hunt-and-peck" method is usually not very productive, though you can get lucky or you may find your own goals changing in the process. Or just give up and find something else to do, I suppose. Better that you create a ***sizzling*** 5-8 lines of text to describe your goals. Doable?

Comment: @periblepsis Yes, the purpose is exactly to create a random number generator from white noise. But I was hoping to still listen to it while generating numbers and maybe change its volume without affecting the flatness and still being able to be read by the comparator

Comment: How many random bits per second do you need to produce? What tests will you be applying to determine 'randomness'? And yes, I now get the idea that you'd like to minimally impact the generation when you "listen" to the noise. So you'd like to design something that doesn't significantly impair the source through the added loading of an amplifier used for human hearing. There may actually be quite a few interesting problems in all this depending upon the details. Part of the reason is that BJTs are very quiet at certain loading levels but JFETs are better in a few other cases. It's not simple.

Comment: I might want to consider the source itself and try and match up either a BJT or a JFET for the pre-amplification setup, together with some prediction written down in a log book followed up by bench testing results added to the log book and a written comparison of prediction vs experimental result. Once the noise source and pre-amp have met prediction (either by me getting better at prediction from theory or by improving the experiment), I'd move on. But only then. Once the transducer (noise generator) and the 1st stage (pre-amp) are out of the way, the rest is all about trading bandwidth.

Comment: Some papers to review would be [here](https://www.eng.auburn.edu/~wilambm/pap/2011/K10147_C011.pdf) and perhaps more appropriately and more recently [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/jnm.3090).